# Lambda expression for getting indexes of list items conditionally

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a `List<bool>`. I need to get the indexes of top n items where item value = true.

For example the following list items(bool)

```
10011001000

TopTrueIndexes(3) = The first 3 indexes where bits are true are 0, 3, 4 
TopTrueIndexes(4) = The first 4 indexes where bits are true are 0, 3, 4, 7
```

How can I write a lambda for this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, assuming you have some easily-identifiable condition, you can do something like this, which will work for *any* `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var query = source.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                  .Where(x => x.value => Condition(value))
                  .Select(x => x.index)
                  .Take(n);
```

(Obviously fill in the appropriate bit of the `Where` clause. If it's just a `List<bool>` it may just be `x => x.value`.)

The important bits are that you use the overload of `Select` to get index/value pairs *before* the `Where`, and then another `Select` to get just the indexes *after* the `Where`... and use `Take` to only get the first `n` results.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could do Select((val, ind) => ...). +1

Comment: @Alxandr: It's one of the things you can do by calling the `Select` method directly but not via a query expression.

Comment: So there's no way to get the index in a query-pattern (except the way I did by simply counting on the outside)?

Comment: I mean, this could probably be written like `from item in list let index = ind++ where Condition(item) select index;` or something like that, right?

Comment: @Jon what would you recommend to read for lamda expression and expression trees ... to get expert skills?

Comment: @Alxandr: You'd have to declare index outside the query, and then you'd have a side-effecting query, which isn't generally nice.

Comment: @Ramiz: I'd recommend practice more than anything else. Lambdas aren't really hard - but they take a certain mindset.

Comment: @Thanks Jon. I'll. Should I consider any read/resource during practice?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Is it possible to have default stating value set for index? something like `source.Select((value, index = 10) =>...`?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: No, but you can use `(value, index) => new { value, index + 10 }`. Note that this days I'd suggest using a ValueTuple literal, so `(value, index) => (value, index: index + 10)`

Answer (score 2):

There's an overload of `Select` where the lambda gets two parameters: the index and the element. So you can just take the indices where the value is true, supplying a sentinel (here, -1) for the ones you don't want. Then filter out the sentinels and take how many you want:

```
bool[] bools = ...;
var indices = bools.Select((val, ix) => val ? ix : -1).Where(i => i >= 0).Take(n);
```

Comment: You have the index and element in the reverse order in your lambda, which will confuse people (confused me). It should be `Select((val,ix)...`.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do it.

```
IEnumerable<bool> GetItemsInList(IEnumerable<bool> list, int count) {
    int ind = 0;
    return list.Select(itm => new {i = ind++, v = itm}).Where(itm => itm.v).Take(count).Select(itm => itm.i);
}
```

Comment: That will just give true, true, true, true... `count` times. It's not giving the *indexes*.

Comment: Sorry, saw that too, and fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Here how it goes:

1. Select `source + its index`
2. Add condition to the `where` clause (the source of the where clause now contains the `original source + index`)
3. Select the `index` (the index returned here is the original index from the original source)

`var indexes = inputList.Select((input, index) => new { input, index }).Where(a => condition(a.input)).Select(a => a.index);`